# Match two specific words

Tags: string, lua, match

Is it possible to find two specific words which are next to each other, with `match` or `gmatch`?

Example:

```
local usb_dfh   =  "Filesystem Size Used Available Use% Mounted on tmpfs"
```

Let's say you try to match "Mounted on". Is this possible?

Info:
My goal is to find `"Mounted on"` and replace it with `"Mounted_on"`.

Comment: "two words" are not different than a string of character with a space in it

Comment: Sure it's possible, have you tried anything?

Comment: i wrote "two specific words".
@YuHao of course, but nothing worked

Comment: Show your code, it's OK if it's not working.

Comment: ok thanks, i will do this in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies, `string.match` and `string.gmatch` are used to *match*. To *replace*, use `string.gsub`:

```
usb_dfh:gsub('Mounted%s+on', 'Mounted_on')
```

`%s+` matches one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: Thx, thats the solution for my problem, but the question remains. Is it possible to match two specific words with match or gmatch? I tried it like this: string.gmatch(mystring, "Mounted on")

Comment: @EdwardBlack That should work. Again, if you don't show your complete code, we don't know where you did it wrong.

Comment: well, thats the main part of the code, i have a string (usb_dfh) and try to match these two words. But nothing happens. But maybe this makes no sense, so forget it.
Code: http://www.pasteall.org/59711/lua

Comment: @EdwardBlack If you print the return value of `string.match`, and it's not `nil`, it means the match succeeds.

Comment: But even when i try `string.gmatch(mystring, "Mounted oasdfn")`
Nothin happens, i don't even get `nil`

Comment: `string.gmatch` is an iterator function, use it in a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much Yu Hao, now with `match` it works!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem.

```
usb_dfh = string.gsub(usb_dfh, "Mounted on", "Mounted_on")
```

But the question remains. Is it possible to match two specific words with gmatch?

Comment: `gmatch` is a iterator.